# Navigation drawer fragment icons doesn't show

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am working on a navigation drawer project and stuck in icons of fragments. Project run's successfully but the icon associated to that particular fragment doesn't show up instead all the fragments have "Home" icon which is for the first one. I am really stuck with this. PFA screen image below and program code:

**MainActivity.java**

[image: Screenshot]

```java
package com.navafatech.navdrawer;

//import android.app.FragmentManager;
//import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
//import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
//import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mDrawerList;
        private android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


        // nav drawer title
        private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

        // used to store app title
        private CharSequence mTitle;


        // slide menu items
        private String[] navMenuTitles;
        private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

        private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
        private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

            // load slide menu items
            navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

            // nav drawer icons from resources
            navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);


            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

            navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

            // adding nav drawer items to array
            // Home
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0]));
            navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0,0);

            // Find People
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1]));
            // Photos
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2]));
            // Communities, Will add a counter here
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3]));
            // Pages
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4]));
            // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5]));


            // Recycle the typed array
            navMenuIcons.recycle();

            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

            // setting the nav drawer list adapter
            adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    navDrawerItems);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

            // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
            assert getSupportActionBar()!=null;
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);



            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle (this, mDrawerLayout,
                   // R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                    R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                    R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
            ) {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // on first time display view for first nav item
                displayView(0);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Slide menu item click listener
         */
        private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
                ListView.OnItemClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                // display view for selected nav drawer item
                displayView(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
            // Handle action bar actions click
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        /***
         * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
            boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        /**
         * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
         */
        private void displayView(int position) {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new PhotosFragment();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new CommunityFragment();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment = new PagesFragment();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

                // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }
    }
```

**NavDrawerItem.java**

```java
package com.navafatech.navdrawer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by navin on 04-11-2015.
 */
public class NavDrawerItem  {
    private  String title;
    private int icon;
    private String count = "0";
    // boolean to set visiblity of the counter
    private boolean isCounterVisible = false;

    public NavDrawerItem (){}

    public NavDrawerItem(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon, boolean isCounterVisible, String count){
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

   public int getIcon() {
      return  this.icon;
}

    public String getCount(){
        return this.count;
    }

    public boolean getCounterVisibility(){
        return this.isCounterVisible;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon){
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public void setCount(String count){
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void setCounterVisibility(boolean isCounterVisible){
        this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
    }
}
```

**NavDrawerListAdapter.java**

```java
package com.navafatech.navdrawer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public  NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return  navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

       //    imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**content_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <!--  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
          android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="#b0c4de"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**drawer_list_item.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
        android:textColor="#0889d8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingEnd="40dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="#001905"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Slider Menu</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="drawer_open">Slider Menu Opened</string>
    <string name="drawer_close">Slider Menu Closed</string>

    <!-- Nav Drawer Menu Items -->
    <string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
        <item >Home</item>
        <item >Find People</item>
        <item >Photos</item>
        <item >Communities</item>
        <item >Pages</item>
        <item >What\'s Hot</item>
    </string-array>

    <!-- Nav Drawer List Item Icons -->
    <!-- Keep them in order as the titles are in -->
    <string-array name="nav_drawer_icons">
        <item>@drawable/ic_home</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_people</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_photos</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_communities</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_pages</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_whats_hot</item>
    </string-array>

    <!-- Content Description -->
    <string name="desc_list_item_icon">Item Icon</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add your array of icons to your navDrawerItems.

## MainActivity.java

```
// adding nav drawer items to array
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
```

## NavDrawerListAdapter.java

Next, you need to set the image resource in your adapter:

```
imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
```

**MainActivity.java**'s `OnCreate()` final code:

```
.....
navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

// adding nav drawer items to array
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

// Recycle the typed array
navMenuIcons.recycle();
....
```

**NavDrawerListAdapter.java**'s `getView()` final code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ......

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Thanx buddy...It's working now with your suggestions. However it was giving error saying "navDrawerItems(string, int) not found" so i changed navDrawerItems(String title) constructor to navDrawerItems(String title, int icon). Is it okk to change the current constructor or should I add one more with two parameters?

Comment: There is no need to, just delete it.

Comment: Thanx JDev...Code is running now :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly see how you are updating your icons. But here is how I did it, you need to create an int array of your icons in the drawer list adapter and then use the position value to simply place the icon at that place.

eg. imgView.setImageResource(iconArray[postion]);

while your int iconArray[] = {R.icon1, R.icon2, .....}